# Why doesn't sum of of the values in the commit size in the processes view match the commit size in the performance view in the Windows Task Manager?

Tags: windows-7, memory, task-manager, commit

`Commit Size` in the `Processes` view:

[image]

Commit size in the `Performance` view:

[image]

Why doesn't sum of of the values in the `Commit Size` in the `Processes` view match the commit size in the `Performance` view in the Windows Task Manager?

Answer (score 1):

We should take into account the shared pages. Typically all loaded DLL are shared and this makes impossible to just sum the commit size of each process and expect it to match the commit size of the whole system.